# How to work with annual country data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

It's my first time using R. I want to create a scatterplot with a line of best fit for a decade of data about all countries. I joined two excel datasets - one has the number of people jailed for a certain crime by country in a given year (rows: country, columns year:, the other has average income for a certain population group (rows: country, columns: year).

```
dataclean=inner_join(EnforcementData, IncomeData, by = "Country")
```

This gives me a dataset with x, y points where enforcement is the x and income is the y

I want to plot this and find the outliers - so those countries where enforcement is out of step with income. I tried:

```
ggplot(dataclean, aes(x=EnforcementData, y=IncomeData, group= "Country")) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = "Country")
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: I think I've improperly merged the datasets somehow, as it returns a matrix. Like this:

> dput(head(dataclean))
> structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
> "Argentina", "Armenia"), `2006.x` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2007.x` = c(0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2008.x` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0), `2009.x` = c(0,
> 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `2010.x` = c(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), `2011.x` = c(0,
> 0, 0, 0, 4, 0), `2012.x` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `2013.x` = c(1,
> 1, 3, 0, 3, 0), `2014.x` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2015.x` = c(0,
> 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), `2016.x` = c(0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0), `2017.x` = c(0,
> 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), `2018.x` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2019.x` = c(0,
> 1, 3, 0, 0, 0), `2020.x` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2006.y` = c(3.273755,
> 2.9912451, 3.689971, 1.342365, 2.8111637, 3.1407325), `2007.y` = c(3.157699,
> 3.0298389, 3.759603, 1.315153, 2.8102016, 3.2122944), `2008.y` = c(3.0636166,
> 3.0644794, 3.754531, 1.181255, 2.9054865, 3.1780076), `2009.y` = c(3.0084051,
> 3.0477934, 3.874565, 1.144331, 2.9149061, 3.0896677), `2010.y` = c(2.9951254,
> 2.9948973, 3.796005, 1.161454, 2.8314702, 3.1664003), `2011.y` = c(3.1528966,
> 3.0144704, 3.814187, 1.190574, 2.8360401, 3.1267727), `2012.y` = c(3.1964009,
> 2.9731618, 3.73838, 1.201921, 2.913096, 3.0577149), `2013.y` = c(3.1683419,
> 2.943247, 3.779373, 1.209151, 2.9020493, 3.0017037), `2014.y` = c(3.0180735,
> 3.0699088, 3.913854, 1.8298544, 3.0114942, 2.9938708), `2015.y` = c(2.9489451,
> 3.1155215, 3.864924, 1.7799824, 3.0169873, 3.0037498), `2016.y` = c(2.8750588,
> 3.1476701, 3.909438, 1.7761061, 2.7538409, 3.041738), `2017.y` = c(2.8906318,
> 3.0717401, 3.880863, 2.2256225, 2.7280908, 3.0332232), `2018.y` = c(2.9485421,
> 3.12678, 3.609102, 2.1923678, 2.5386973, 2.8175096), `2019.y` = c(3.0029988,
> 3.0910585, 3.524361, 2.1915031, 2.5461976, 2.6481938), `2020.y` = c(1.9297139,
> 3.1117555, 3.3970031, 2.1946293, 2.5862916, 2.438313)), row.names = c(NA,
> -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Try with no quotes in `group= "Country"`.

Comment: The `x=` and `y=` arguments in the `aes()` function refer to dataframe **columns**, but you've passed them names that correspond to two other dataframes. Also `geom_line()` does not create a scatterplot - for that you need `geom_point()`. Please show us what `dataclean` looks like (you could edit your question to paste the output of `dput(head(dataclean))` so we can better understand how to help you.